# Why do multiple loop cuts appear when I try to add only one?

Tags: modeling

Okay so I was trying to model something for a friend. and when I made a paw mesh. and joined it to the legs. it does this when I try to add a loop cut?
[image: multiple loop cuts instead of one. this happens on 2.79 (the version I use) and the current version as you can see.]

Comment: do you want the loop cut to slice through the highlighted horizontal face loop area? can you share a blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, I presume the topology is spiraling. What you perceive as multiple cuts is probably a single cut on that topology. This happens often when the topology was generated with some auto-retopo mechanism.
To check if this indeed the cause, select the edge loop, it will be clear if it's clean or not.